# How to check if process already exists in python script?

Tags: python, process-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check for process already running in webfaction?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17316/check-for-process-already-running-in-webfaction)

How can I check if a process is already being run using Python + Django on WebFaction hosting?

For example, my process name is `myfile.py`

Comment: Please [do not cross post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting). Ask on the site you think most appropriate, then if you change your mind flag it to be migrated so you don't waste people's time resolving a question that is being worked on and maybe even solved elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pidfile with any programming language. It's very easy.

There are some examples in [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788411/check-to-see-if-python-script-is-running).

Comment: Instead of saying "it's easy in any language" and linking elsewhere, it would be better to provide a working example customized to the context of this question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't want a copy/paste response, any simple example in python is useful for the question.